# Having problems with some setInterval + jQuery FadeIn/FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to fade in / out some text inside a div. I've kept the time really quick for debugging purposes. The problem is that I think the fade in and outs are fighting each other. Sometimes the text is updated and then it fades in/out.

[See this interactive example on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCadu/)

Here's the code :

```
var tips = [
    'AAA',
    'BBB',
    'CCC'
];

var currentTipIndex = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    currentTipIndex++;
    if (currentTipIndex >= tips.length) {
        currentTipIndex = 0;
    }
    $("#pewpew").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#pewpew").html(tips[currentTipIndex]);
    $("#pewpew").fadeIn(1000);
}, 1 * 5 * 1000);​
```

It's like want the interval timer to stop. then fade out. (wait for fade to finish). update text. fade in. (wait for fade in to start). Then start timer again.

Comment: Use callback functions with fadeOut and fadeIn. See http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
// Rotating Tips.
var tips = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'];

var currentTipIndex = 0;

function recursiveTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        currentTipIndex++;
        if (currentTipIndex >= tips.length) {
            currentTipIndex = 0;
        }
        $("#pewpew").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $("#pewpew").html(tips[currentTipIndex]);
        });

        $("#pewpew").fadeIn(1000, recursiveTimeout());
    }, 1 * 5 * 1000);

};
recursiveTimeout();
```

Using the fadeOut callback ensures that the animation has finished before loading the content. Then creating a recursive callback within the fadeIn, starts the timer when it's completed.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCadu/2/ .

Comment: This answer helped with my situation @infra-stank thanks! I am curious though, as to why you multiply by 1 instead of 5 * 1000 on the fadeIn callback function timer? *noob question :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var tips = [
    'AAA',
    'BBB',
    'CCC'
];

function fadeIn(html) {
    $("#pewpew").html(html);
    $("#pewpew").fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $("#pewpew").fadeOut(1000, getNextTip);
    });
}

var currentTipIndex = 0;
function getNextTip() {
    if (currentTipIndex >= tips.length)
        currentTipIndex = 0;

    var cTip = tips[currentTipIndex];
    fadeIn(cTip);

    currentTipIndex++;
}

$(function() {
    getNextTip();
});
​
```